Why was IVF in Rhino not believed to be possible?
This line from here:

We achieved together something which was not believed to be possible.

suggests IVF in Rhino was not believed to be possible.
Why was IVF in Rhino not believed to be possible?

I’m voting to close this question because the function of this site is to answer questions about biology, not about the perceived difficulty of a particular obscure process, according to authors of a paper.

@David - Once again, I disagree with your somewhat narrow definition of Biology. Ecology is a specialty field in biology, just as is Molecular Biology or Medicine. Questions about ecology on topic. This isn't a question about reproductive medicine, but one of Ecology (though the OP misunderstood that.) To answer ecology questions, and in so doing to teach, who knows what might come of it? Close for lack of research if you will, but not because "it's not about Biology".

This is actually an English language question, not a rhino reproduction question. The line before the one you quoted is

The technique could be used to save the northern white rhino from total extinction.

The northern white rhino is on the verge of extinction, and it looks like a sure thing in the natural world. As with climate change tipping points, for animals the tipping point for extinction is followed by a rapid decline in population numbers because there are too few remaining individuals on earth to reverse the process; extinction is considered irreversible.
The article states that there are only two female white rhinos left on earth, a pretty sure sign that they will become extinct soon.  However, suddenly the zoologists have hope to prevent extinction (through IVF). It's not that IVF was impossible. It's that the white rhino may not disappear off the face of the earth after all.
They did what they thought was impossible. They may have saved a species from extinction.
